# Mapping multiple language data in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, mapping

guys! I'm still beginner so I have a problem with mapping in JS if I have multiple langauges to map. With react I could to solve it with the useState and useEffect but in this case I don't know what do do...

```
    function report() {
  const reportWindow = document.getElementById("reportWindow");
  const pageName = window.location.pathname;
  const language = document.getElementsByTagName("html");
  let codeBlock = "";

  for (let i = 0; i < language.length; i++) {
    if (language[i].lang === "en") {
      codeBlock = `
    <div class="report__base" id="myReport">
    <span id="close" onclick="showOld()">&times;</span>
    <div class="report__content" id="report01">
    <h3>Report page</h3>
    <form method="post" action="https://saro.website/report.php" class="report__form">
    <input name="language" id="language" value="${language[i].lang}" style="display: none;">
    <input name="page" id="page" value="${pageName}" style="display: none;">
    <input name="lang" id="lang" value="English" style="display: none;">
    <select name="category" id="category" required>
    <option value="Bug">Bug</option>
    <option value="Page does not work">Page does not work</option>
    <option value="Problem with displying">Page displays incorrectly</option>
    <option value="other">Other</option></select>
    <input type="text" name="other" id="other" class="issue" placeholder="if other, what is it?">
    <textarea name="describe" id="describe" cols="30" rows="10" placeholder="Describe your issue or feedback here" required></textarea>
    <i>*Additional informations name, email are not requested</i>
    <div class="form__label__left">
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="issue" placeholder="Name">
    <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="issue" placeholder="Email">
    <input type="submit" class="button__black" value="Send">
    </form>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>`;
    } else if (language[i].lang === "ja") {
      codeBlock = `
    <div class="report__base" id="myReport">
    <span id="close" onclick="showOld()">&times;</span>
    <div class="report__content" id="report01">
    <h3>レポート</h3>
    <form method="post" action="https://saro.website/report.php" class="report__form">
    <input name="language" id="language" value="${language[i].lang}" style="display: none;">
    <input name="page" id="page" value="${pageName}" style="display: none;">
    <input name="lang" id="lang" value="Japanese" style="display: none;">
    <select name="category" id="category" required>
    <option value="Bug">バグ</option>
    <option value="Page does not work">ページがうまく動かない</option>
    <option value="Problem with displying">指定したページが一致しな</option>
    <option value="other">その他</option></select>
    <input type="text" name="other" id="other" class="issue" placeholder="「その他」を選んだ方は、内容をご記入下さい?">
    <textarea name="describe" id="describe" cols="30" rows="10" required placeholder="発生している状況やフィードバックをご記入下さい"></textarea>
    <i>以下の内容をご記入下さい。(任意)</i>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="issue" placeholder="お名前">
    <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="issue" placeholder="メールアドレス">
    <input type="submit" class="button__black" value="送信">
    </form>
    </div>
    </div>`;
    } else if (language[i].lang === "zh") {
      codeBlock = `
    <div class="report__base" id="myReport">
    <span id="close" onclick="showOld()">&times;</span>
    <div class="report__content" id="report01">
    <h3>问题反馈</h3>
    <form method="post" action="https://saro.website/report.php" class="report__form">
    <input name="language" id="language" value="${language[i].lang}" style="display: none;">
    <input name="page" id="page" value="${pageName}" style="display: none;">
    <input name="lang" id="lang" value="Chinese" style="display: none;">
    <select name="category" id="category" required>
    <option value="Bug">问题</option>
    <option value="Page does not work">页面 没 有 反应</option>
    <option value="Problem with displying">页面 显示 错误</option>
    <option value="other">其他</option></select>
    <input type="text" name="other" id="other" class="issue" placeholder="如果 是其他问题， 是 什 么？">
    <textarea name="describe" id="describe" cols="30" rows="10" required placeholder="在这里描述下 你的 问题 或 反馈 "></textarea>
    <i>附加 信息， 不 需要</i>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="issue" placeholder="名字">
    <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="issue" placeholder="邮件">
    <input type="submit" class="button__black" value="发送">
    </form>
    </div>
    </div>`;
    }

    reportWindow.innerHTML = codeBlock;
  }
}
```

There is a code, but I would to love to make it more clear and readable I would like to leave only one codeBlock as a varible and don't multiple it. Somebody could to help me and solve it in JS? ^^" thanks in advance - I would love to expand my knowladge about JS so it would be helpful in my studying this language.

Answer (score 0):

You're in the right way, that code needs to be simplified!

And you're purpose to expand your knowledge is mirable.

JavaScript is perfect for HTML page manipulation. Sometimes you use frameworks or libraries like React or Vue.js, JQuery, Angular to make things cleaner and easier.

There are also libraries which simplify language translation inside our code, like for example I18N.

If you write in plain JavaScript (called *Vanilla JS*), sometimes you have to write, debug, maintain a lot of code. You should consider to use a framework or at least a library.

In this case I really suggest you to:

- avoid to put HTML strings inside JavaScript code, it's not very readable
- avoid to duplicate code. You could simplify it for example using a language map like in the example below and then modifying the HTML using classes and ids.

```js
const languageMaps = {
  'en': {
    'bug': 'Bug',
  },
  'ja': {
    'bug': 'バグ',
  },
  // ...
};

const language = 'en';

document
  .getElementById("bug-option")
  .firstChild
  .nodeValue = languageMaps[language].bug;
```

I know it's not that much, but I hope it could help.

Good luck with your study!

Comment: Thank you it's really helpful :) I will try in this way! I just realized I got some minus because of I've asked about helping, I feel little sad that in this website are some toxic people as well :(

Comment: I'm sorry about that... In my opinion we all should ask for help from the community, even the good ones  Good coding JoJo!

Comment: You really helped me out! I could solve it! Big thanks to you :) and thanks for these words! I try my best to practice JavaScript. I'm originally frontend developer but I'm really interested in JavaScript so why after react js I want to start studying node js! cus my dream is being a fullstack developer exactly working with JavaScript :)